# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: php

```
function clear_code($var) 
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}
```

Функция работает, но почему то бъет кодировку. Как исправить?

Comment: Что значит "бъет кодировку"?

Comment: "Ñ�ÐµÐºÑ�Ñ�"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите кодировку для функции `htmlentities`:

```
function clear_code($var) 
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}
```

Подробнее: [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php)